# Why is my friend picker fragment empty?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I went over this thread [Empty Facebook FriendPickerFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886731/empty-facebook-friendpickerfragment) but I found that I have the requirements that person addressed - "user_friends" permission, approval from facebook team etc. Everything else works - login process, but is there a reason why the friend picker fragment is empty? I was able to start the friend picker activity but I got was a activity that had Choose Friends and Done at the top. The friends list is empty.
I don't want to post my code because most of it comes from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends

Also got a failed binder transaction. Does that mean something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine was empty because I was the only one using the app. Because I am using facebook api graph 2.0, it only shows friends who are using the app.